# apache mod_headers custom header

Tags: apache-2.2

Folks,
  Trying to add a custom header with mod_headers.  Need to set the 'Date' Header for AWS S3 via mod_headers.  I am trying to do the following in the apache config:

```
RequestHeader add Authorization "AWS AWSAccessKeyId:Signature"
RequestHeader set Date "%{DATE_GMT}e"
```

Its not working , and im trying to find out why.  I've setup logging (for testing) as

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{Date}i %{Authorization}i" common
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! At the end of the day, I would like to have a Date: Header added in the following format:

```
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:42:41 +0000
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your question is completely unclear right now.

Comment: The mod_headers module can set the Headers header via %t to be 1970+ format, instead of the Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:42:41 +0000

Comment: Put here dump of HTTP request to your server. And give us server logs

Comment: Did this work ?

Answer (score 0):

RequestHeader directives adds Headers to a request meant to be proxied to another server.

You want to use the directive `Header add (...)`

Just change `RequestHeader` by `Header` and see how it goes.